# Multiple subsets

Tags: r, row, subset

Could you suggest a more elegant solution to the following problem? Remove rows containing more than one 0 in columns x,z,y or a,b,c.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 1:5, z = 0:4, a = 4:0, b = 1:5, c=0)
```

my solution (row 1 and row 5 should get removed)

```
df_new <- subset(df, ((((x != 0 & y  !=  0) | (x  != 0 & z   !=  0) | (y  != 0 & z   !=  0)) & ((a  != 0 & b   !=  0) | (a  != 0 & c   !=  0) | (b  != 0 & c   !=  0)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# 1:3 is same as columns 'x', 'y', 'z', Similarily for 4:6 . 
# You can also specify the colnames explicitly
# add a na.rm = T inside rowSums() incase you also have missing data
(rowSums(df[, 1:3]==0)>1)|(rowSums(df[, 4:6]==0)>1)

# did you mean this ?
df[!((rowSums(df[, 1:3]==0)>1)|(rowSums(df[, 4:6]==0)>1)),]
#  x y z a b c
#2 0 2 1 3 2 0
#3 0 3 2 2 3 0
#4 0 4 3 1 4 0
```